# wxPython automatically does event at startup when it shouldn't

Tags: python, user-interface, events, wxpython

So, I am pretty new to programming. I am currently making a simple text editor (claaaassic) in wxPython on Mac. I have a the "Save" menu item bound to the event saveFile() which takes a custom class file() as a parameter for the directory and file type of the designated file. Everything looks normal, but for some reason, the method is called automatically at startup, and doesn't run when I actually clicked the Save menu item. Any help would be much appreciated!

Also, the code below is just a sample of my program.

```
import wx

# Custom class file
class file():
    def __init__(self, directory, file_type):
        self.directory = directory #location of file
        self.file_type = file_type #type of file (text, HTML, etc.)

# Main Frame
class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Program', size=(500, 700))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.Exit)
        self.f1 = file("/Users/Sasha/Desktop/File.txt", "Text File")   # an example file
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        # the reason we use "self.text" instead of just "text", is because if we want to use multiple windows, I believe
        self.menu()
        # Last. Centers and shows the window.
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    # Save file, WHERE I HAVE PROBLEMS
    def saveFile(self, a, file):
        directory = file.directory
        file_type = file.file_type
        file = open(directory, "r+") #r+ is reading and writing, so if file is same, no need to write
        print file.name + ",", file_type
        l = file.read()
        print l
        file.close()

    # Exit method, pops up with dialog to confirm quit
    def Exit(self, a):
        b = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Do you really want to close this application?", 'Confirm Exit', wx.CANCEL | wx.OK)
        result = b.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()
        b.Destroy()

    def menu(self):
        # A shortcut method to bind a menu item to a method
        def bindMethod(item, method):
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, method, item)

        # FILE
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        new = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New")
        save = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")
        saveAs = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save As")
        bindMethod(new, self.newFile)
        bindMethod(save, self.saveFile(self, self.f1))    # WHERE I MAY HAVE PROBLEMS
        bindMethod(saveAs, self.saveAs)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")  # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame1()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the method on the same line where you think you bind it. Instead of passing the method, you pass the return value of the method called.

In this line, the second parameter is a method:

```
bindMethod(new, self.newFile)
```

In this line, the method is called and second parameter is whatever is returned, e.g. None:

```
bindMethod(save, self.saveFile(self, self.f1))
```

When you bind methods, the parameters and not used, so you bind to the method name and do not call it at that place. The wxPython should call the bound method with correct parameters when event is fired.

That also probably means that you cannot use parameters that you have, as callback for `wx.EVT_MENU` is given. You would need to create some kind of file dialog to get those parameters in the `saveFile` method.

Comment: So basically, when I call the bind, I can't call parameters, because that's actually doing the method, and not binding it? And so then you mean, I would have to find some way of choosing the `self.f1` file WITHIN the `saveFile` method?

Comment: @SashaAhrestani Exactly.